# Should I hardcode data or use props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and was wondering if we have to use hardcode data like this:

```
import React from "react";
    import "../src/App.css";

    const header = props => {
      return (
        <header>
          <h1>Content Manager</h1>
        </header>
      );
    };

    export default header;

    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import Header from "../src/header";

    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Header />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

As you can see the code above, I just put "Content Manager" inside h1 as a usual content just like we do in HTML. Or do I need to use props instead of hardcoding:

```
import React from "react";
import "../src/App.css";

const header = props => {
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
    </header>
  );
};

export default header;


import React, { Component } from "react";
import Header from "../src/header";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header title={"Content Manager"} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Guys if something is not clear please let me know

Comment: If you want to make this component reusable, then use `props`.

Comment: It also depends, for example if is the main page, you can show your application name that can be stored in a .properties or .env file. When creating a new component, think always on reusability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically If you want to reuse a component you should be using props.

Example:

When you need same header component for 3 places saying "Welcome","Hello" and "Hi" and have hard coded you will result in writing 3 header components with your heading as "Welcome","Hello" and "Hi".

something like this:

```js
    const HiHeader = props => {
      return (
        <header>
          <h1>Hi</h1>
        </header>
      );
    };

    export default HiHeader;
    
       const HelloHeader = props => {
      return (
        <header>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
        </header>
      );
    };

    export default HelloHeader;
    
       const WelcomeHeader = props => {
      return (
        <header>
          <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </header>
      );
    };

    export default WelcomeHeader;


and you use them as

<HiHeader/>
<HelloHeader/>
<WelcomeHeader/>
```

in case, if you use props you can write a single header and pass different props.

example :

```js
const header = props => {
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
    </header>
  );
};

export default header;


import Header  from './header.js'

<Header title="Hi"/>
<Header title="Hello"/>
<Header title="Welcome"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your header component going to be reused to display different headers pass in the text as a prop. Else, if you are dead sure that this is gonna be used only once, hard coding is fine.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

**Never hardcoding, it's the evil!**

Comment: localStorage, fetch, ReactJS props, JS/HTML dataset, or global file containing some key and values. There are many workarounds to hardcoding. My apologies.